# Angular library won't compile because of some component with private properties

Tags: angular, build

I'm creating a new library base on bootstrap for angular (yep, another one but why not ?) and I have a weird problem with (only !) two components.
They both have private properties (like many other components), which are only accessed from within, not from the template, the linter says everything's okay, but when I build (ng build bootstrap), I get those errors:

> BUILD ERROR
>   projects/bootstrap/src/lib/components/checkbox-button/checkbox-button.component.html(2,2): : Directive ButtonDirective, Property '_class' is private and only accessible within class 'ButtonDirective'.

(and many more fore this component and another one especially)

And here is the checkbox-button.component.html template:

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle">
    <label #button tabButton [isToggled]="isToggled" [tabState]="state" [toggleable]="true" tabindex="0" (toggled)="toggled($event)">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </label>
</div>
```

As you can there is no use of the '_class' property in it.

Does anyone has any idea ?

EDIT:
I'm on angular 7

EDIT 2:
I found the problem. It was a mistake in an index file where I was exporting from the spec.ts file instead of the ts file.

Comment: could you add some more inf. about your env.? Eg. angular/cli versions.

Comment: Delete your `dist` folder and build again. You might have some caching issues.

Comment: @ogTag I have no dist doler, it's the first time I try to build this library